# Custom message on plugin uninstall

Tags: plugins, uninstallation

I'm writing a small wordpress plugin that creates some custom files, but I'm wondering if there is a way to show a quick "reminder" pop-up or message when a user deactivates the plugin.

I just want to remind the user to download their custom files before deleting the plugin data, as it deletes the files when the plugin gets deleted.

It's not meant to be intrusive at all, just a simple reminder.

I tried the answer here ["pop-up asking to confirm data deletion"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65611/popup-asking-whether-data-should-be-removed-on-plugin-uninstall), but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Why does your plugin store data in files?

Comment: In addition, what have you tried?  What did you not understand?  Try looking here too: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979

Comment: It uses files because in this case a file is created to send to employees